# Deprecated API Usage - New apps that use UIWebView are no longer accepted(React Native)

Tags: ios, react-native, uiwebview

UIWebview found in these folder but i'm not able to get replace it into WKWebView, I get using on project directory :

```
grep -r UIWebView ./*
```

> Binary file
> ./node_modules/react-native-maps/.gradle/4.10.3/taskHistory/taskHistory.bin
> matches Binary file
> ./node_modules/@philly25/react-native-paytm/ios/libPaymentsSDK.a
> matches
> ./node_modules/@philly25/react-native-paytm/ios/PGTransactionViewController.h:@interface
> PGTransactionViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate,
> UIActionSheetDelegate>
> ./node_modules/jsc-android/dist/include/JSContextPrivate.h:/*!
> @abstract The delegate the context will use when trying to load a
> module. Note, this delegate will be ignored for contexts returned by
> UIWebView. */ ./node_modules/ua-parser-js/test/browser-test.json:
> "ua"      : "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_0_2 like Mac OS X)
> AppleWebKit/602.1.50 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/14A456 QQ/6.5.3.410
> V1_IPH_SQ_6.5.3_1_APP_A Pixel/1080 Core/UIWebView NetType/WIFI
> Mem/26", ./node_modules/fbjs/lib/UserAgent.js.flow:   * - UIWebView
> ./node_modules/fbjs/lib/UserAgent.js:   * - UIWebView
> ./node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/node_modules/fbjs/lib/UserAgent.js.flow:
>
> - - UIWebView ./node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/node_modules/fbjs/lib/UserAgent.js:
> - - UIWebView

when i upload then i find the same issue that

> New apps that use UIWebView are no longer accepted. Instead, use
> WKWebView for improved security and reliability.

I would really appreciate your help with any kind of hint. Let me know if you need additional information.